# Multiple drop down menus returning data in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two drop down menus that use the same iframe to display data from the queries being run.  The problem is that the second menu is only returning the data from the first menu.  I've tried changing the select id variables but it hsn't made a difference.  How can I set this up so that both menus pull the data they're supposed to?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>

<title>Side Bar</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<style>

div {
    text-align: justify;
    }

.section {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 70%;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<nav>
<br>
    <h1>Fixed header</h1>
<br>
    <h2>Subheader</h2>
    <ul>
<br>

<form>
<p><b>Our Staff</b>

  <select id="mySelect" onchange="select_change()">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="Illustrators">Illustrators</option>
    <option value="TechWriters">Tech Writers</option>
  </select>
</p>
</form>

<div class="center">
<script>

var iframeExists = false;

function select_change() {
  var my_select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var my_select_value = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].value;

  var x;
  if (!iframeExists) {
    x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframeExists = true;
  } else {
    x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
  }
  if(my_select_value) {
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/" +
                          my_select_value + ".php");
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
  }
}

</script>

</div>

<form>
<p><b>Our Projects</b>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="select_change()">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="CurrentProjects">Current Projects</option>
    <option value="ProjectsInFinalReview">In Final Review</option>
    <option value="CompletedProjects">Completed Projects</option>
  </select>
</p>
</form>

<div class="center">

<script>
var iframeExists = false;

function select_change() {
  var my_select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var my_select_value = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].value;

  var x;
  if (!iframeExists) {
    x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframeExists = true;
  } else {
    x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
  }
  if(my_select_value) {
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/" +
                          my_select_value + ".php");
    document.body.appendChild(x);    

}

</script>

</div>
<br>






</div>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Logistics</h1>
<br>
<h2>Tech Orders</h2>

<div class="section">
<p>YAI has been extensively involved in the writing of technical manuals, provisioning and Modification Work Orders (MWOs) for all type of military aviation and ground systems. YAI logistic services have included development and assessment of logistical requirements, preparation of integrated logistic products and field service support  for military aviation, missile and ground combat systems.</>

<p>YAI's Logistic Capabilities include:</p>

<ul>

<li>Technical Manual Writing</li>

<li>Technical Manual Change Pages</li>

<li>Manual Illustrating</li>

<li>MWO Writing</li>

<li>Tagging of Data for Use in Electronic Manuals</li>

<li>Provisioning</li>

<li>Logistical Analyses and Assessments</li>

</ul>

</div>

        </div>

        <footer>
            ..
        </footer>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Assuming this is the same domain as where the page runs, why not Ajax the data? Also why a php file per project instead of using `"getData.php?project="+my_select_value`

Comment: It's for a school assignment and the requirement was to use php.  The script for the queries is run on separate pages on my domain.  I'm calling each individually and displaying them in the iframe.

Comment: I did not say "don't use php" I said use ONE php file and check the `$_GET["project"]` for which project you pass in

Comment: I've never used Ajax and I'm only now learning php.  I'm not sure how to set up what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second **select_change()** to **select_change2()**, and change the second **mySelect** id to **mySelect2**. Also, you're missing a closing curly brace to end your if in the second select_change().

When you add javascript in a script tag, that code is global. So you made two methods named select_change(). Only one can exist, so it looks like the browser chose to use the first one. The same goes with id. You shouldn't have two elements with the same id on one page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang = "en">
      <head>

    <title>Side Bar</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <style>

    div {
        text-align: justify;
        }

    .section {
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         width: 70%;
        }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <nav>
    <br>
        <h1>Fixed header</h1>
    <br>
        <h2>Subheader</h2>
        <ul>
    <br>

    <form>
    <p><b>Our Staff</b>

      <select id="mySelect" onchange="select_change()">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="Illustrators">Illustrators</option>
        <option value="TechWriters">Tech Writers</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    </form>

    <div class="center">
    <script>

    var iframeExists = false;

    function select_change() {
      var my_select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      var my_select_value = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].value;

      var x;
      if (!iframeExists) {
        x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        x.setAttribute("id", "IF1");
        iframeExists = true;
        document.body.appendChild(x);    
      } else {
        x = document.getElementById("IF1");
      }
      if(my_select_value) {
        x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/" +
                              my_select_value + ".php");
      }
    }

    </script>

    </div>

    <form>
    <p><b>Our Projects</b>
      <select id="mySelect2" onchange="select_change2()">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="CurrentProjects">Current Projects</option>
        <option value="ProjectsInFinalReview">In Final Review</option>
        <option value="CompletedProjects">Completed Projects</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    </form>

    <div class="center">

    <script>
    var iframe2Exists = false;

    function select_change2() {
      var my_select = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
      var my_select_value = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].value;

      var x;
      if (!iframe2Exists) {
        x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        x.setAttribute("id", "IF2");
        iframe2Exists = true;
        document.body.appendChild(x);    
      } else {
        x = document.getElementById("IF2");
      }
      if(my_select_value) {
        x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/" +
                              my_select_value + ".php");
      }
    }

    </script>

    </div>
    <br>

    </div>
        </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="main">
                <h1>Logistics</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>Tech Orders</h2>

    <div class="section">
    <p>YAI has been extensively involved in the writing of technical manuals, provisioning and Modification Work Orders (MWOs) for all type of military aviation and ground systems. YAI logistic services have included development and assessment of logistical requirements, preparation of integrated logistic products and field service support  for military aviation, missile and ground combat systems.</>

    <p>YAI's Logistic Capabilities include:</p>

    <ul>

    <li>Technical Manual Writing</li>

    <li>Technical Manual Change Pages</li>

    <li>Manual Illustrating</li>

    <li>MWO Writing</li>

    <li>Tagging of Data for Use in Electronic Manuals</li>

    <li>Provisioning</li>

    <li>Logistical Analyses and Assessments</li>

    </ul>

    </div>

            </div>

            <footer>
                ..
            </footer>

        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

edit: I updated it to use separate iframes.

Comment: I've tried several varitions of that but when I change the mySelect id in the second script it stops the first one from working as well.

Comment: You need to also change the method names since they're global. They can't be named the same thing. The code I posted should be working. But they are sharing the same iframe.

Comment: I've tried a number of variations but I'm obviously missing something.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: I see where you did that.  I never considered that.  I tried your code and it pulls data from both menus; but it's now crossing the data.  For example when I select menu 1 it pulls from menu 2 and vice versa

Comment: Yeah the issue is that you're appending the element to the body each time. You only need to append it when you first add it to the document. See the code I edited in my answer. Of course whichever one you create first will come first. If you want to change this you can write the iframes into the html and just edit them with javascript.

Comment: Yes, notice I moved the "document.body.appendChild(x);" for both methods. Also don't forget to accept the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: I saw that.  I tried the code, but now it on;y loads the second mune.  I'm going to try coming at this again tomorrow.  It's 2am here and I'm beat.  I know there's got to be something that we're over looking because this should be working.  I used a single iframe when I had this set up using onclicks.  I just wanted to use the drop down menus because they're cleaner